# Composer not autoloading files included through repositories > type > path

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

## The Problem

I have two PSR-4 composer projects and I wish to classes from one in the other, the file structure is as follows:

```
projectfoo
-public
--index.php
-src
--CompanyName
---Foo
----Foo.php
-composer.json
projectbar
-src
--CompanyName
---Bar
----Bar.php
-composer.json
```

The composer.json files are defined for projectfoo as (note the repositories > type > path dependency):

```
{
    "name": "companyname/foo",
    "require": {
        "companyname/bar": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../projectbar"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CompanyName\\": "src/CompanyName"
        }
    }
}
```

And projectbar as:

```
{
    "name": "companyname/bar",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CompanyName\\": "src/CompanyName"
        }
    }
}
```

Running `composer update` correctly produces the vendor folder containing the companyname/foo folder.

In `index.php` in projectfoo I have:

```
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$bar = new \CompanyName\Bar\Bar();
```

However, when run `\CompanyName\Bar\Bar` is undefined.

---

## The question

Why is `Bar` not being included in the autoload.php file?

---

## What I've tried

- Refreshing the autoload file using:
  `composer install`
  `composer update`
  `composer dump-autoload`
- Changing the vendor name `CompanyName` to something different.
- Looking at the `installed.json` file in the `vendor\composer` folder the bar project is listed as:

#

```
{
    "name": "companyname/bar",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "version_normalized": "1.0.0.0",
    "dist": {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../companyname/bar",
        "reference": "f35ed0ad82c8280db9b603712dd256074f99e196",
        "shasum": null
    },
    "type": "library",
    "installation-source": "dist",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CompanyName\\": "src/CompanyName",
        }
    }
}
```

- Strangely, when bootstrapping the autoload.php file to phpunit the files autoload correctly and are available in my test classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue revolves around the way composer links "path" projects using symlinks.

---

## In short

Because I was developing on a windows system and executing the code on an Ubuntu vagrant box the symlinks set up on windows, when running `composer install` were resolving to broken paths inside the box. This also explains why tests run on windows managed to locate `Bar` but not tests run in the virtual box.

---

## Solutions

To solve this I initially forced composer to mirror the project rather than symlink it, however, this still caused issues with symlinks in the vendor folder.

I have now started hosting my libraries in seperate repositories and importing them using the `"type": "vcs"` tag which works well. Composer also handles updating package when new commits are made which doesn't happen when using the `"type": "path"` tag with mirroring.